# JS: Update an attribute of the latest added element after push() in a loop does not assign the correct value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

I have the following code:

```
var nameData = [{id: "1", name: "George,Steve,Andy"},{id: "2", name: "Andy,Bradley"},{id: "3", name: "George"},{id: "4", name: "Joseph,Julia"}]
var newNames = []
for (var c=0; c<nameData.length; c++) { 
    //create an array of names
    var names = nameData[c].name.toString().split(",")

    //loop through the name array and for each name add a new entry in the newNames array
    for (var n=0; n<names.length; n++) {
            newNames.push(nameData[c])
            newNames[newNames.length-1].name = names[n]
    }                           
}
```

My output here is the following:

```
0: {id: "1", name: "Andy"}
1: {id: "1", name: "Andy"}
2: {id: "1", name: "Andy"}
3: {id: "2", name: "Bradley"}
4: {id: "2", name: "Bradley"}
5: {id: "3", name: "George"}
6: {id: "4", name: "Julia"}
7: {id: "4", name: "Julia"}
```

However, my desired output would be this:

```
0: {id: "1", name: "George"}
1: {id: "1", name: "Steve"}
2: {id: "1", name: "Andy"}
3: {id: "2", name: "Andy"}
4: {id: "2", name: "Bradley"}
5: {id: "3", name: "George"}
6: {id: "4", name: "Joseph"}
7: {id: "4", name: "Julia"}
```

Something is wrong with the assignment of the `name` attribute in the loop. All entries from one `id` get the last name in the `name` attribute. Why is that and how to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `newNames.push(nameData[c]);` which will pass the object reference. Instead first clone the object and then push.

```js
var nameData = [{id: "1", name: "George,Steve,Andy"},{id: "2", name: "Andy,Bradley"},{id: "3", name: "George"},{id: "4", name: "Joseph,Julia"}]
var newNames = []
for (var c=0; c<nameData.length; c++) { 
    //create an array of names
    var names = nameData[c].name.toString().split(",")

    //loop through the name array and for each name add a new entry in the newNames array
    for (var n=0; n<names.length; n++) {
            newNames.push(Object.assign({}, nameData[c]));
            newNames[newNames.length-1].name = names[n];
    }                           
}

console.log(newNames);
```

You can also use `reduce`.

```js
var nameData = [{id: "1", name: "George,Steve,Andy"},{id: "2", name: "Andy,Bradley"},{id: "3", name: "George"},{id: "4", name: "Joseph,Julia"}]

const output = nameData.reduce((accu, {id, name}) => {
    name.split(",").forEach((name) => accu.push({id, name}));
    return accu;    
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: That works. Could you add some explanation for why my code won't work?

Comment: Based on your edit: I know that it pushes the same object, but I thought by doing `newNames[newNames.length-1].name = names[n]` I adjust the last inserted object in the new array `newNames` and thus makes it a new object (?)

Comment: @JoeBe - I'am extremely sorry. You are passing object reference - `newNames.push(nameData[c])`. Instead you can clone the object and then push - `newNames.push(Object.assign({}, nameData[c]));`.

Comment: I just figured out that this solution is still wrong because I don't maintain the object's attributes (e.g. in your example I don't have `{id: "...", name: "..."}` but rather `{"[value of id]" : "[value of sponsor]"}`. I want to copy the object and just adjust the `name` attribute

Answer (score 0):

if you like reduced solutions you could:

```
nameData.reduce((a, { id, name: names }) => 
    a.concat(names.split(',').map(name => ({id, name})))
, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer provider a precise explanation.
However, I think the reason you encountered this problem is not only
the code implementation, bu also code design.

Your implementation in `low level abstraction`,
you do it in imperative, so you need to handle too many detail, 
like `loop control`, `mutate reference` and so on.
I prefer refactor it in `functional style`.

```js
const newNames = nameData.flatMap(data =>
  data.name.split(",").map(name => ({
    id: data.id,
    name
  }))
);
```

I guess what you want to do is:
Flat `newData` by split `name`.

So as you can see, the above example just [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap') it,
and you don't need handle the loop detail.

Further more,
because the `map` or `flatMap` is immutable style function and we get new data
by copy but not mutate the reference,
we don't need to care either about reference or mutate the original data.

Tip: the flatMap is new feature come from `JS`, take care about compatibility.